# Server and client network apps simulated in one machine

Tags: docker, systemd

I would like to simulate a server machine and several client machines operating over a vpn.  I would like to test the server application as well as the client applications all on one machine.

Would I be able to do this with a few docker applications running on my machine - or should I be using something like systemd-nspawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. With [linking](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/) containers, [exposing](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) and publishing[publish ports containers can communicate with each other or with the host machine.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're hoping to accomplish. If you want to perform end-to-end tests (for example, two chat clients connect and send each other messages through the server) then Docker is an excellent solution. If you want to do performance testing, then Docker is not a great fit (at least by itself).

Comment: I would be looking to do performance (what happens when I spawn 10 to 1000 client applications.